# find the instantaneous rate of growth

Tags: calculus

If the population growth ($P$) in a community is projected to follow the function $P= 7t^2 + 5t + 350$ ($t$ is time in years), then find the instantaneous rate of growth from the second year to third year.

Answer (score 2):

$P'(t)=14t+5$

$P'(2)=33$

Therefore $33$ is your answer.

To get this answer I took the derivative of your function and got the rate at which $P$ changes with respect to $t$

Comment: how did it become 14t+5? if you don't mind explaining it

Comment: You have to take the derivative. This a calculus concept, and the rules of its operations can be found online. In this case I used the power rule.

Comment: A part of the question was left out so that solution is not correct but I think i know how to do it from there

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is not at all clear. It asks for the "instantaneous rate of growth from the second to third year", as if there is a single number for the answer. But "from the second to third year" the "instantaneous rate of growth" is continually changing, per the formula 14*t + 5, as t increases continuously from 2 to 3.